# How can a Barco ClickShare device share different content to two different monitors?

Tags: video-streaming, microsoft-teams, presentations, screen-sharing

*(Not sure if this is the right community in StackExchange so direct me if in wrong place.)*

We have meeting rooms with two monitors up front. In the past we would show presentation on one monitor and person speaking on the other.

We have bought a Barco [ClickShare C-10](https://www.barco.com/en/clickshare/wireless-presentation/c-10) for our meeting room that allows you to plug in your own device.

What I wanted to know is is it possible on a Microsoft Teams call to direct your screen outputs to different monitors?

Currently screen output is being mirrored to both devices (bottom of picture). We want it to be as per the top?

[image: Screens]

We have been told it is **not possible** and the "solution" is to spend more on converting the room to a Microsoft Teams Room.

Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

did you get an answer to your question?

We have the same problem, we found it very annoying as so many promotional images suggested exactly this scenario.

Anyway, since a few days Barco has released the solution with the CX-50 2nd generation. Which addresses exactly your problem described above. We will test it.

For you, just google.

"Barco Just Added Two Outputs to the ClickShare CX-50!" on the ravepubs page.

or on youtube

ClickShare CX-50 2nd generation product video

We couldn't believe that such a simple requirement had not yet been met in the market.

Many greetings from Germany

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1170297)

Comment: Vielen dank MaWi for sharing this.